# How to achieve pages like a math notebook in css?

Tags: css

Hey i'm a beginner to CSS so can anyone tell me how can i achieve the background of a site as a page from kid's maths notebook.
Below is the image i want to place.

[image: Background texture]

Comment: it is a repeated background-image

Comment: yeah it sure does allow to post image....or post the image link, i'll add it for you....meanwhile you can try setting the background for page through `background:url('/path-to-image');background-size:100% 100%;` ...see if it helps !! :)

Comment: i don't have 10 points which is must for posting/uploading images. here's the link "http://tinypic.com/r/2isgoxh/5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/yng7j/1/

CSS:

```
html{
    background-image: url('http://s8.postimg.org/v2ugecde9/background.png');

}
```

Take a look at the image. Basically, it's just a small white rectangular with a purple border on the top and on the left. It automatically gets repeated in x and in y direction.

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't match your answer.

Comment: what should i do in it if i want this in every page of my site which has header, body and footer as different pages? how can i do it in separate css file??

Answer (score 2):

The solution above does not work anymore and anyway I think that a simpler (and more configurable) solution will be to use the CSS function `linear-gradient` like this:

```css
body{
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 1px, transparent 0px), linear-gradient(black 1px, transparent 0px);
}
```